# Using both DNS and host headers, point to a sub-folder within an existing website

Tags: domain-name-system, iis

I have an existing website that is a ASP.NET website:

```
www.example.com
```

This website is served by IIS at say the folder:

```
c:\websites\example.com\www\
```

Now I want to use another domain name for a customer:

```
www.example2.com
```

This website will be served from the same source folder as example.com, but it will point to a subfolder like:

```
c:\websites\example.com\www\folder1\folder2\
```

Is this possible to do?

I only want the files under folder2 to be served from the domain example2.com

Comment: What is the problem you are having?

Comment: We want to use the same codebase to serve from 2 different domains.  But the 2nd domain from only a subset of the main website.